# Detect which orientation a bitmap taken from the camera should be

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an app that the client has asked to add rotation support.
Below is the current code that takes the image from the camera.

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                        if (data != null) {

                            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                            mtx.postRotate(180);

                            float density           = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;

                            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, (data != null) ? data.length : 0);
                            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                            bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(scaled, (int)(480*density), (int)(320*density), true);       //height and width are backwards because its portrait
                            previewImage(bm);
                        }
                    }


                });
```

What I am trying to work out is the quickest way to work out what orientation the captured bitmap should be in, i.e when the user takes a picture with the device in landscape we need to flip:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(scaled, (int)(480*density), (int)(320*density), true);
```

to:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(scaled, (int)(320*density), (int)(480*density), true);
```

and also change the mtx.postRotate

My issue is working out the best way to find out what rotation the image was taken in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private Bitmap checkForRotation(String filename, Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = bitmap;
    ExifInterface ei = null;
    try {
        ei = new ExifInterface(filename);
        new ExifInterface(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {

     //Here you get the orientation and do what ever you want to do with it as i am rotating the image

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        myBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);

        break;
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        myBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;
    }
    return myBitmap;
}
```